# Is it possible to change the date time values dynamically while running the code in scala

Tags: scala

I have a data like below:

```
val jsonData = "{\n  \"id\":\"" + a + "\",\n  \"Category\":\"Flink\",\n  \"eventTime\":\""+dateTime+"\"\n  \n}"
```

I also created a `DateTime` variable that gets the `current timestamp`.

```
val dateTime:String =DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(LocalDateTime.now)
```

Now I have a for loop for a creating a dataset:

```
for (a <- minRange to maxRange) {
      jsonData = "{\n  \"id\":\"" + a + "\",\n  \"Category\":\"Flink\",\n  \"eventTime\":\""+dateTime+"\"\n  \n}"
      println(jsonData)
      Thread.sleep(500)
    }
```

Now what I am trying to achieve is, I want to replace the values of the `eventTime` attribute in the `JSON` data dynamically. It is the `event time` of the record. Time at which record arrived at the source. But, when I tried to run the sample code it gave me the output like below:

```
{
  "id":"10",
  "Category":"Flink",
  "eventTime":"2021-12-26 21:09:53.217"
  
}
{
  "id":"11",
  "Category":"Flink",
  "eventTime":"2021-12-26 21:09:53.217"
  
}
```

As we can see it is giving me the timestamp when the code ran which is correct but is it possible to get it dynamically like `"eventTime":"2021-12-26 21:09:55.589"`, `"eventTime":"2021-12-26 21:09:58.800"`?

Comment: Do you know the difference between `val` and `def`? This isn't even a Scala specific issue, you will face the same issue if you rewrite this in Python.

Comment: No. Could you please explain?

Comment: Do you know the difference between variables and functions? You need to make `dateTime` call `LocalDateTime.now` every time it is referenced, not just once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the variable `dateTime` with its value should fetch you the dynamic `event time`.

```scala
for (a <- minRange to maxRange) {
  jsonData = "{\n  \"id\":\"" + a + "\",\n  \"Category\":\"Flink\",\n  \"eventTime\":\""+DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(LocalDateTime.now)+"\"\n  \n}"
  println(jsonData)
  Thread.sleep(500)
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "id":"0",
  "Category":"Flink",
  "eventTime":"2021-12-26 23:03:04.609"
  
}
{
  "id":"1",
  "Category":"Flink",
  "eventTime":"2021-12-26 23:03:05.114"
  
}
{
  "id":"2",
  "Category":"Flink",
  "eventTime":"2021-12-26 23:03:05.616"
  
}
```